# getting the value of textbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to MVC. I'm developing an application. The application contains two textboxes. The first textbox allows users to type in a code. For example, the code could be `1204033333`. All I want to do is to get the first four digits of the first texbox and display them with the to second the textbox. For example if the user types `1204033333`, I want the value of the second textbox to be 12.04. That means the first four digits with . at the middle.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? What is your structure? What resources have you looked at to try and figure it out yourself?

Comment: For the people downvoting this, its this guys first question asked ever (see his profile) give him some advice and tips instead, like @ZachSaucier

Comment: @TeunPronk Being the first question ever asked is not a proper excuse for asking a bad question. In fact, there is no excuse for not doing proper research before asking a question.

Comment: Downvotes are advice - the advice is "This question is not good enough, read the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help)" Specifically: [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Also, Stackoverflow gives you a gigantic amount of advice before you're allowed to post your first question. If you don't skip through this content, of course.

Comment: Doing both is however far more constructive. Downvote, comment with explanation as to why OP is being downvoted.

Comment: @Haruna Ado: Do you want to solve the problem using a panel update on submit (e.g. an MVC Ajax call) or using jQuery (as they type it)? It would be *really useful* if you provided more details of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

Alright: 
First you need to add an id to both of your input boxes

```
<input type="text" id="input1" />
<input type="text" id="input2" />
```

Now you can easily access them with JavaScript:

```
var input1 = document.getElementById("input1");
var input2 = document.getElementById("input2");
```

Next you bind an eventlistener to your input1

```
input1.onchange = inputChangeHandler;
function inputChangeHandler(e){
  input2.value = input1.value.substr(0,1) +"."+ input1.value.substr(2,3);
}
```

This code was not tested, so you might need to change some stuff, but this is the basic idea.
What I don't understand is you talk about MVC, but this has absolutely nothing to do with MVC...

Comment: The question was also tagged with jQuery, so surely a jQuery answer will be simpler than this raw javascript one (e.g. like user2314737's answer)?

Comment: sure, it would be shorter... But I provided an all javascript answer, where a a big library like jQuery is not needed. If jQuery is needed anyway (for other stuff) you're better off with user2314737's answer

Answer (score 1):

Create two input boxes

```
   <input type='text' id='mybox' > 
   <input type='text' id='mybox2' >
```

In Javascript/Jquery update the value of the second textbox every time the first one is updated:

```
var myval;
$('#mybox').on('input', function () {
    myval = $(this).val();
    $('#mybox2').val(myval.substring(0, 2) + '.' + myval.substring(2, 4));
})
```

Here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/K99GA/2/

Comment: I like this one for using the input event. Nice and simple. You could simplify with `$(this)` in the event though as `myvar` should only be local to the callback.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way would be to use something like jQuery to manipulate your DOM objects.

Use jQuery's `.val()` function for getting and setting the values in the `<input>` elements.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vQ4W3/) to get you on your way. (It also includes conditions for when you have less than 4 characters in the first `<input>`)

Happy coding! :)

Comment: A jQuery answer *should* have been shorter than a Javascript one... See user2314737's answer (which also updates as you type).

Answer (score -1):

Its best to show what you tried.

Also I dont want to just give you the answer, I think its better to point you in the right direction.
To get the value of a textbox you can use the `.val()` function in jQuery. [Link](http://api.jquery.com/val/).
To copy strings you can use the [substring function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp)

I hope you can figure it out from here :)